# Array splice with key name

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, array-splice

I have 2 arrays ($data_1 & $data_2) which have different value but have a relation, I want to merge those array, completely with key name

```
$data_1 = 
'[
    {
        "fruit": "apple",
        "weight": "15"
    },
    {
        "fruit": "durian",
        "weight": "50"
    },
    {
        "fruit": "orange",
        "weight": "10"
    }
]';


$data_2 =
'[
    {
        "color": "red",
        "thorn": "no"
    },
    {
        "color": "green",
        "thorn": "yes"
    },
    {
        "color": "orange",
        "thorn": "no"
    }
]';
```

but I want to combine those array, then I have a full data like this:

```
$full_data = 
'[
    {
        "fruit": "apple",
        "weight": "15",
        "color": "red",
        "thorn": "no"
    },
    {
        "fruit": "durian",
        "weight": "50",
        "color": "green",
        "thorn": "yes"
    },
    {
        "fruit": "orange",
        "weight": "10",
        "color": "orange",
        "thorn": "no"
    }
]';
```

I tried with `array_splice()`

```
for ($i=0; $i < count($data_2); $i++) { 
    array_splice($data_1[$i], 0, 0, $data_2[$i]);
}
```

but it returns with '0' and '1' not original key name...

```
'[
    {
        "fruit": "apple",
        "weight": "15",
        "0": "red",
        "1": "no"
    },
    {
        "fruit": "durian",
        "weight": "50",
        "0": "green",
        "1": "yes"
    },
    {
        "fruit": "orange",
        "weight": "10",
        "0": "orange",
        "1": "no"
    }
]';
```

I want to replace that '0' and '1' into the original key names

Comment: Use `array_merge` instead of `array_splice` and assign it to first array or to a new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `array_merge` to merge two arrays.

```php
$full_data = [];
for ($i=0; $i < count($data_2); $i++) { 
    $full_data[$i] = array_merge($data_1[$i], $data_2[$i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply, you could do it by

1. convert two arrays format json into two php arrays using `json_decode` function.
2. iterate over one of them and fill `$full_data` with values of two arrays respectively.
3. display the array with format json using `json_encode` function.

```php
// 1.
$data1 = json_decode($data_1,true);
$data2 = json_decode($data_2,true);

// 2.
$full_data = [];
for ($i=0; $i < count($data1); $i++) { 
    $full_data[$i] = $data1[$i] + $data2[$i];
}
// 3. 
echo(json_encode($full_data));
/*
[
 {"fruit":"apple","weight":"15","color":"red","thorn":"no"},
 {"fruit":"durian","weight":"50","color":"green","thorn":"yes"},
 {"fruit":"orange","weight":"10","color":"orange","thorn":"no"}
]
*/
```